# Painting mutliple objects in 1 JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make my program object oriented and I'm attempting to split it into several classes. The short version is that I want to paint  different objects in 1 `JFrame`. So I created a class per object that I wanted to paint, defined the object in my method and then add them to my frame. The problem is that only the last component is painted in the frame. I tried adding the objects to a `JPanel` first but that doesn't seem to work.

### `trees1`

```
public class trees1 extends JComponent{

public final ImageIcon  pokemontree;

public trees1(){
    ImageIcon poke = new ImageIcon("pokemontree.png");

    Image image = poke.getImage(); // transform it 
    pokemontree = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    pokemontree.paintIcon(this,g2 , 100,200);
}
}
```

### `testing`

```
// main program
public class testing {

public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame win = new JFrame();
    win.setSize(600,400);
    win.setTitle("Test");
    win.setResizable(false);
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    trees1 exo = new trees1();
    Playerwalking p1 = new Playerwalking(1,2);
    win.add(exo);
    win.add(p1);

    win.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: First, you want to understand how the layout management system works, start by having a read through [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). `JFrame` by default uses a `BorderLayout` (see [How to use `BorderLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)), which will only manage a single component at any of it's 5 available positions, this is what you only see your last object

Comment: Without knowing more details, I would recommend using a `JLabel` to paint the `ImageIcon`

Comment: *"Painting mutliple objects"* Keep a list or collection of them. In a single `JPanel` override the `paintComponent(..)` method, call the `super` method then iterate the collection and paint each in turn to a single `Graphics` object. Done. General advice: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0):

JFrame content pane default uses BorderLayout

The default content pane will have a BorderLayout.

For BorderLayout, the "add()" method always set to "CENTER" if you don't specify the location (NORTH/EAST/SOUTH/WEST/CENTER etc) of the components you adding.

You need to specify your "getPreferredSize()" in your component, also understand how to use the BorderLayout (or other layout manager properly).

```
public class Test1 extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame win = new JFrame();
    win.setSize(600,400);
    win.setTitle("Test");
    win.setResizable(false);
    win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    win.add(new trees1(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    win.add(new trees1(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    win.add(new trees1(), BorderLayout.EAST);

    win.pack();
    win.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

class trees1 extends JComponent {

```
public final ImageIcon pokemontree;

public trees1(){
    ImageIcon poke = new ImageIcon("c:\\temp\\2.png");

    Image image = poke.getImage(); // transform it
    pokemontree = new ImageIcon(image);  // transform it back
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(pokemontree.getIconWidth(), pokemontree.getIconHeight());
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    pokemontree.paintIcon(this,g2 , 0,0);
}
```

}

Comment: And forgot the mention you shouldn't paint at (100,200) unless you always want your icon to be offset by that relative distance to the top left corner of your component.